Is this Collatz-like stochastic process almost surely bounded?
I recently asked a question about whether a stochastic process $X =(X_n)_n$ could exhibit two properties at the same time, namely that $P(\sup_n X_n < \infty) = 1$ while $E(X_n) \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$. I had a specific example in mind, but feedback I received on that question made me realize that there was an error in my argument. So I would now like to present the example and ask whether it does in fact satisfy these two properties.
The process is as follows. Take $X_0 = 0$ almost surely, and for each $n \geq 0$ choose independently and uniformly whether to take $X_{n+1} = X_n/2$ or $X_{n+1} = (3X_n+1)/2$. It is possible to prove by induction that $E(X_n) = n/4$ for each $n$. Essentially: if $X_n$ is supported on a finite set with average value $n/4$, then by linearity $X_{n+1}$ is supported on a finite set with average value
$$ \frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{n}{4}\Big)\Big) + \frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big(\frac{n}{4}\Big) + \frac{1}{2} \Big) = \frac{n+1}{4} $$
and therefore $E(X_n) \to \infty$ is satisfied, but the other question remains.
Let $S = \sup_n X_n$, which may be infinite.

Is it the case that $P(S < \infty) = 1$?

The process $X$ will be easier to analyze if we represent it in another way. Let
$b=(b_i)_{i=0}^\infty$
be a sequence of iid random bits, which are the choices at each $i$ whether to take $X_{i+1}$ as $X_i/2$ or $(3X_i+1)/2$. Assuming that $X_n$ is computed deterministically from $b_0, b_1, \ldots, b_{n-1}$, a formula for $X_n$ may be derived.
Almost surely there are infinitely many $i$ for which $b_i = 1$; let them be enumerated by $(i_k)_{k=1}^\infty$. Also, let $c_n$ be the count of $i \in [0,n)$ for which $b_i = 1$ (i.e., the number of appearances of $1$ in the first $n$ bits drawn from the sequence $b$). Then $X_n$ is given as follows.
$$ X_n = \sum_{k=1}^{c_n} \frac{3^{c_n - k}}{2^{n-i_k}} = \frac{3^{c_n}}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{c_n} \frac{2^{i_k}}{3^k} $$
The proof of this is derived from expanding $X_n$ as a sum of terms of the form $3^{u}/2^{v}$ (interpreting an empty sum, in the case that there are no terms, as yielding the value $0$). If $b_n = 1$, then $X_{n+1} = (3X_n+1)/2$ and therefore the sum accrues one new term of $1/2 = 3^0/2^1$, while every other term has both $u$ and $v$ increased by $1$. Otherwise, if $b_n = 0$, then $X_{n+1} = X_n/2$ and therefore the number of terms stays the same while every $v$ is increased by $1$. Apply this logic inductively over the first $n$ bits in the sequence $b$ to see that each appearance of $1$ seeds a term of $1/2$, which then accrues as many $2$s in the denominator as there are terms ahead up to $b_{n-1}$, and which accrues as many $3$s in the numerator as there are $1$s ahead up to $b_{n-1}$. This counting argument then translates into the sum above.
Observe that $c_n = b_0 + b_1 + \cdots + b_{n-1}$ is a sum of iid uniform variables with mean $1/2$, and therefore for large $n$ we have that $c_n$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $n/2$. Moreover, $i_k = (i_k - i_{k-1}) + \cdots + (i_2 - i_1) + i_1$ is a sum of iid geometric variables with success probability $1/2$ (and thus mean $2$), and therefore for large $k$ we have that $i_k$ is also approximately normally distributed with mean $2k$. In an idealized average case, we would therefore have the following.
$$ X_n \sim \frac{3^{n/2}}{2^n} \sum_{n=1}^{n/2}\frac{2^{2k}}{3^k}  = \Big(\frac{3}{4}\Big)^{n/2}\cdot \frac{4}{3}\Big(\frac{1-(4/3)^{n/2}}{1-(4/3)}\Big) = 4 - 4\Big(\frac{3}{4}\Big)^{n/2}$$
The fact that $3/4 < 1$ and therefore $(3/4)^{n/2} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ is what suggests to me that $S = \sup_n X_n$ should be almost surely finite. However, when I attempt to make the argument above precise, I can't make it go through. By the observations above, for each $\delta > 0$ it holds almost surely that $c_n < (n/2)+\delta n$ and $i_k < 2k + \delta k$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and $k$. However, by careful choice of $\delta$, this is only enough to conclude that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ it holds almost surely that $X_n < 4e^{\varepsilon n}$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Is there any way this argument can be strengthened to show that $(X_n)_n$ is almost surely bounded?

I found a paper which studies a similar random process and, using a similar argument as in that paper, I believe I can prove that in fact, $P(S = \infty) = 1$; the claim that $P(S < \infty) = 1$ is not true.
Note that $X_n \geq 0$ holds for every $n$, and let $N$ be fixed. With probability $1$, there is an $n$ such that $b_n = b_{n+1} = \cdots = b_{n+N-1} = 1$. In which case, it holds that $X_{n+1} \geq 1/2$, $X_{n+2} \geq 3/4$, ..., and $X_{n+N} \geq 3^{N-1}/2^N$. This implies that
$$ P\Big(\sup_n X_n > \frac{1}{3}\Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^N\Big) = 1 $$
Since $N$ was arbitrary and $(3/2)^N \to \infty$ as $N\to\infty$, we may thus take a countable intersection:
$$P(\sup_n X_n = \infty) = P\Big(\bigcap_N \Big[\sup_n X_n > \frac{1}{3}\Big(\frac{3}{2}\Big)^N\Big]\Big) = 1 $$
In other words, because there are almost certainly arbitrarily long runs of consecutive applications of $(3(\cdot)+1)/2$, it means that $X_n$ must eventually grow arbitrarily large.

I would like to know more about how $(X_n)_n$ grows in a typical case. We see that it must be unbounded, but at the same time it cannot grow too quickly. Indeed, the analysis of $X_n$ using the central limit theorem above indicates that $\frac{1}{n}\log (X_n) \to 0$ almost surely.
Between bounded and exponential, what is the true "typical" growth rate of $(X_n)_n$? Based on the expectation formula $E(X_n) = n/4$, one would expect $X_n$ to grow linearly. Is it the case, then, that $\frac{1}{n}X_n$ converges to something, either almost surely or in distribution?
